# Pro Tools tutorials

Tags: pro-tools

Can somebody point me to some good pro tools tutorial from beginners to pro level.

Your suggestion/feedback are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's three good free sources:

- ["Official" Pro Tools Forums](http://duc.avid.com/index.php)
- [Avid's Pro Tools channel on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=165D5E8741F7614E)
- [www.protoolsguides.com](http://www.protoolsguides.com/)

If you're willing to pay you could also check out the [groove3 videos](http://www.groove3.com/str/pro-tools-training/).  I haven't used them myself but I've heard they're good.

Answer (score 2):

Home Studio Corner (http://homestudiocorner.com/blog)

Pensado's Place (http://pensadosplace.tv)

Answer (score 1):

Here some usable tips for protools. Lot more on youtube though.

http://homerecording.about.com

http://www.lynda.com/tutorial/74534